# MySQL: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'pb' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

MySQL5.7 I have the query:

```
UPDATE payment_bak pb JOIN
(
    select p.customer_id 
    from payment_bak p 
    where p.amount = (select max(amount) from payment_bak) 
) temp ON pb.customer_id= temp.customer_id 
SET pb.payment_date=now();
```

It returns the error:

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'pb' for update in FROM clause
```

it looks a little strange because there is no any 'pb' in FROM clause. But my question is why this query works well if I add DISTINCT?

```
UPDATE payment_bak pb JOIN
(
    

select DISTINCT p.customer_id 
        from payment_bak p 
        where p.amount = (select max(amount) from payment_bak) 
    ) temp ON pb.customer_id= temp.customer_id 
    SET pb.payment_date=now();
```

Could you explain me please.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to update payment date to `now()` for customers who have the max amount in the database?

Comment: I am trying to update payment date for all payments of customers who have at least one payment with max amount in the database

Comment: I believe this is a bug (or feature) in 5.7 and 8.0. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6fc0e8ee39537860f3f6ba3b0b154aad. The query will work without the distinct in 5.6 but not in 5.7 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6fc0e8ee39537860f3f6ba3b0b154aad

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4fa95d91150e39b52d2d4174ff6dcfb0 query without the `distinct` that works in 5.7 and 8.0

Comment: @zedfoxus thank you very match! Your answer is very helpful!